# Is there an equivalent in Scala to Python's more general map function?

Tags: python, scala, iterable, applicative

I know that Scala's Lists have a [map](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/List.html#map%28%28A%29%3D%3EB%29) implementation with signature `(f: (A) => B):List[B]` and a [foreach](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/List.html#foreach%28%28A%29%3D%3EUnit%29) implementation with signature `(f: (A) => Unit):Unit` but I'm looking for something that accepts multiple iterables the same way that the Python [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) accepts multiple iterables.

I'm looking for something with a signature of `(f: (A,B) => C, Iterable[A], Iterable[B] ):Iterable[C]` or equivalent.  Is there a library where this exists or a comparable way of doing similar?

Edit:

As suggested below I could do

```
val output = myList zip( otherList ) map( x => x(0) + x(1) )
```

but that creates a temporary list in between steps.  If the commentor would post I could upvote him (hint, hint) but is there another way?

Comment: If `zip()` doesn't work, what do you need done differently?

Comment: son of a... zip.  Righto!  Didn't even think of that.  Why don't you post so I can upvote it.

Comment: I'll leave @Mike to answer, but you can do `list1 zip list2` and also `(list1, list2).zipped`. The latter, Scala 2.8 only, doesn't create a temporary collection. Also, you can do `list1.view zip list2` or `list1.projection zip list2` on Scala 2.8 and 2.7 respectively to avoid creating temporary collections.

Comment: No, no, please post so I can upvote that too.  Others may ask the same question at a later date.  Really, zip isn't all that I need.  I need to apply a function to members of both lists to produce the third, final list.

Comment: I remember the original question asking about a solution in Python.  Am I going insane?

Comment: No, you just read wrong.  I was asking about an equivalent to Python in Scala.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In scala 2.8, there is a method called zipped in Tuple2 & Tuple3 which avoid to create temporary collection.
Here is some sample use case:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.r21561-b20100414020114 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_18).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val xs = 0 to 9
xs: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive with scala.collection.immutable.Range.ByOne = Range(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> val ys = List.range(0,10)
ys: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> val zs = Array.range(0,10)
zs: Array[Int] = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> (xs,ys).zipped.map{ _+_ }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18)

scala> (zs,ys,xs).zipped.map{ _+_+_ }
res2: Array[Int] = Array(0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27)

scala>
```

There is a zip method in both Tuple2 and Tuple3. 
xs.zip(ys) is the same as (xs,ys).zip

**Note:** There is also some shortage in (xs,ys).zip and (xs,ys).zipped, make sure that xs can't be a INFINITE Stream. Go to [Ticket #2634](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2634) for more information.
I have [a post](http://old.nabble.com/Some-ideas-of-lazy-version-takeWhile-method-in-TraversableLike.-td28189940.html) in nabble.com some days ago which shows my opinions about how to fix this ticket.

Answer (score 11):

The function you're looking for is usually called `zipWith`. It's unfortunately not provided in the standard libraries, but it's pretty easy to write:

```
def zipWith[A,B,C](f: (A,B) => C, a: Iterable[A], b: Iterable[B]) =
  new Iterable[C] {
    def elements = (a.elements zip b.elements) map f.tupled
  }
```

This will traverse only once, since the implementations for `zip` and `map` on iterators are fully lazy.

But why stop at `Iterable`? This has an even more general form. We could declare an interface for all data structures that can be zipped this way.

```
trait Zip[F[_]] {
  def zipWith[A,B,C](f: (A,B) => C, a: F[A], b: F[B]): F[C]
}
```

For example, we can zip functions:

```
trait Reader[A] {
  type Read[B] = (A => B)
}

def readerZip[T] = new Zip[Reader[T]#Read] {
  def zipWith[A,B,C](f: (A,B) => C, a: T => A, b: T => B): T => C =
    (t: T) => f(a(t),b(t))
}
```

There turns out to be an even more general expression of this type. In general, type constructors that allow an implementation of this interface are [*applicative functors*](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html)

```
trait Applicative[F[_]] {
  def pure[A](a: A): F[A]
  def map[A,B](f: A => B, a: F[A]): F[B]
  def ap[A,B](f: F[A => B], a: F[A]): F[B]
}
```

An implementation of zipWith is then just this:

```
def zipWith[F[_],A,B,C](f: A => B => C, a: F[A], b: F[B])
                       (implicit m: Applicative[F]) =
  m.ap(m.map(f,a), b)
```

This generalises to functions of any arity:

```
  m.ap(m.ap(m.ap(m.map(f,a), b), c), d)
```

The [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) library provides Applicative instances for a lot of data structures in the standard library. Also, convenient syntax is provided for `ap`. In Scalaz, this function is called `<*>`:

```
def zipWith[F[_]:Applicative,A,B,C](f: A => B => C, a: F[A], b: F[B]) =
  (a map f) <*> b
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have so very much to learn.  This was very educational.

Answer (score 3):

There is a method `map2` in the `List` object in Scala 2.7 (and 2.8, but it's deprecated in favor of `zipped`).  You use it like so:

```
List.map2( List(1,2,3) , List(4,5,6) ) { _ * _ }  // Gives List(4,10,18)
```

Eastsun's already shown how to use `zipped` in 2.8 (which works on all collections, not just lists).

Comment: I appreciate the 2.7 comment.  I'll be transitioning to 2.8 soon enough.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't *know* the syntax `(f: (A,B) => C, Iterable[A], Iterable[B] ):Iterable[C]` (and I know *nothing* of Scala), but if I had to guess, it would mean "A function *f* taking two iterable arguments *A* and *B* and returning an iterable *C*".  I'm not sure if this implies that all iterables yield the same number of items.

In Python, I think you're looking for the [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
>>> A = range(10, 15)
>>> B = range(1000, 1500, 100)
>>> zip(A, B)
[(10, 1000), (11, 1100), (12, 1200), (13, 1300), (14, 1400)]
>>> [a + b for a,b in zip(A, B)]
[1010, 1111, 1212, 1313, 1414]
```

`zip`'s output is only as long as the shortest iterable:

```
>>> A=range(10, 12)
>>> zip(A, B)
[(10, 1000), (11, 1100)]
```

Anyway, some built-in Python functions everyone needs to know but easily misses: `enumerate`, `map`, `reduce`, and `zip`.  `filter` used to be on that list, but it's clearer and more flexible to use a list comprehension these days.